# How should I open python file that was Ui

Tags: python, user-interface

I tried to open my python file.It was Ui file.I learn python and I want to make user interface but I don't know where to open it.I know that this is a very stupid question,but noone shows it in courses and videos on coursehunter or youtube.
This is my interface.py:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(503, 679)
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.message_box = QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.message_box.setObjectName(u"message_box")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.message_box)

        self.message_input = QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.message_input.setObjectName(u"message_input")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.message_input)

        self.message_button = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.message_button.setObjectName(u"message_button")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.message_button)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 503, 26))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.message_box.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Connecting ...", None))
        self.message_input.setPlaceholderText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Type your message here ...", None))
        self.message_button.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Send", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

This is my main.py:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.message_button.clicked.connect(self.button_handler())

    def button_handler(self):
        self.message_box.appendPlainText(
            self.message_input.text
        )
        self.message_input.clear()

app = QApplication()
window = MainWindow
window.show()
app.exec_()

How to open this file?
I tried to open it in command prompt but it didn't work.Please help
```

Comment: There's a few things missing; You're missing import statements, and you should post what command you tried to use to run it.

Comment: I just didn't define it here.

Comment: do you means `python main.py`  in console ?

Comment: text `didn't work.` is the most useless information. If you get error message then show it in question. Don't expect that we wil run code to see error. And code may works correctly on our computers.

Comment: This is python file which has elements of GUI.I don't know where to run.What program should I use?